# provides YouTube suggestions using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app for elderly people using flutter, the app will requires the elderly to select the subject he interested in then, in the home of the app I want to provide YouTube videos about that subject so for example if he chose news this will provided in the home
[image]

and if he clicked in the video it will be opened in the YouTube app I want the suggestions to be changed every 2 hours and he can chose more than one subject. any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_api for searching for videos on the topic entered by user and display the videos using https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter to display the videos.

Import the libraries in your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  youtube_api: ^0.8.0
  youtube_player_flutter: ^7.0.0+7
```

Then inside your stateful widget where you display the videos, add this function after the build method and call it in initState

```
void videoList(query) async{
   static String key = 'YOUR_API_KEY';# Get one by following this https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application
   YoutubeAPI ytApi = new YoutubeAPI(key,Type:"video",maxResults:20);
   List<YT_API> ytResult = [];
   ytResult = await ytApi.search(query);
   ytResult.forEach((video){
      String url = video['url'];
      videoId = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(url);
      YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
        initialVideoId: videoID,
        flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: false,
        ),
      ); 
      widgetList.add(Container(
         width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.9,
         child: YoutubePlayer(
           controller: _controller,
           showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
           videoProgressIndicatorColor: Colors.amber,
           progressColors: ProgressColors(
             playedColor: Colors.amber,
             handleColor: Colors.green[800],
           ),
           onReady () {
           },
         ),
      ); 
      widgetList.add(SizedBox(height:30));
      setState((){});
   });
}
```

**INIT STATE**

```
void initState(){
   super.initState();
   videoList(query);#I have declared the variables in next code block
}
```

**VARIABLES DECLARATION**

```
List<Widget> widgetList= [];
String query = "";
```

**IN BUILD**

```
body:Container(
  color:Colors.white,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child:Column(
      children:<Widget>[
       //Add a text field or a dropdown for the subject entry and set its on submit to (value){setState((){query=value});)
       SizedBox(height:30),
      ]+widgetList
    )
  )
)
```

I have written this code without an editor so you will have to make changes but this is basically the code

Comment: yes please I want some sample and if it's ok for you if we can contact on twitter

Comment: Added the sample code. You will have to debug it but this is basically it. Dont forget to get an API key from the url  provided in the comments

Comment: I have some questions can you give me your twitter please??

Comment: I am not on social media. But you can contact me on my mail :- siddharthagrawal2006@gmail.com

Comment: I sent u an email

Comment: Provided the answer. Feel free to contact me for more queries

Comment: sorry but what dose the setState dose in videoList ??

Comment: The setState() rebuilds the page after the data has been loaded. You can use future buillder which is kind of a better way to do this but I have been doing stuff like this for a long time

Comment: hello can u check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66938246/flutter-youtube-player-flutter-7-0-07-http-request-errot